# Equation with complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How would you be able to solve this equation?

$$
z^2 \overline z = z
$$

for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Have you tried anything towards solving the question? If you have you may edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial solution is $z=0$. Now suppose $z\neq 0$. Then since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field you may divide by $z$ and solve the easier equation
$$ z\bar{z}=1 $$
Therefore the solutions are $0$ and all complex numbers with norm $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$z=x+iy$$ then you have to solve $$(x+iy)^2(x-iy)-(x+iy)=0$$
It is equal to $$\left( x+iy \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-1 \right) =0$$